# Running jQuery inside $(window).load() function but not inside $(document).ready function

Tags: jquery

I have this existing function that will icons in a web page using jQuery UI position plugin:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
var element_selector='.test';
if ( $(element_selector).length !== 0) {

//jQuery UI Position code here

}

 });
</script>
```

This function is found near the footer section of the HTML although in some places it outputs on the head section. Someone suggested me to load this jQuery inside $(window).load() function. The reason is that $(document).ready event is fired when DOM is loaded, so it’s fired when the document structure is ready, but before images are loaded.

$(window).load() event is fired after whole content is loaded. So .position() method might not calculate correct position when it’s fired to early (before images are loaded).

If this true, how to revise the above load in $(window).load(). Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I have changed from:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
```

To this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
```

And I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

It fails on this line:

```
$(divname515e62e8355b0).children().wrapAll('<div class="mydoc cf">');
```

where  divname515e62e8355b0 is the selector define here:

```
var divname515e62e8355b0 = '#test_selector';
```

Comment: The 'if' line in your code has an error: it should have a close bracket before the curly bracket.

Comment: Also, I expect the answer to your second question is that the argument passed into the '$' parameter is probably not jQuery. Most likely it is actually an event object. I would just remove the '$' parameter - it's likely unnecessary anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
    var element_selector='.test';
    if ( $(element_selector).length !== 0) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function , see my updated question above..

Comment: remove dollar from first line, should be ok

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is possible jquery's document ready function will sometimes fire before images are fully ready as well. I have found that to be the case when developing parallax sites. Use plain javascript, attach to the window.onload event like this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 window.onload = function(){
  var element_selector='.test';
  if ( $(element_selector).length !== 0 {

  //jQuery UI Position code here

  }
 };
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

JQuery window.onload function is use like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {  

 var element_selector='.test';
 if ( $(element_selector).length !== 0 {

 //jQuery UI Position code here

 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nope - window.load is not the jQuery approach. Further, using window.anyEvent or document.anyEvent is generally considered bad practice - you should be using addEventListener (web standards) and attachEvent (ie8 & lower), so that you can be sure you won't override existing event handlers.