# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function when changing jQuery loading method

Tags: jquery

This is related here: [Running jQuery inside $(window).load() function but not inside $(document).ready function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826498/running-jquery-inside-window-load-function-but-not-inside-document-ready)

Before I am using:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
```

to load my jQuery UI position code but I decided to try to load using:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
```

Now I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

This is my code before the change:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
var element_selector='.test';
if ( $(element_selector).length !== 0) {

var divname515e62e8355b0 = '#test_selector';
$(divname515e62e8355b0).children().wrapAll('<div class="mydoc cf">');

//jQuery UI Position code here

}

 });
</script>
```

This is my code after the change:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
var element_selector='.test';
if ( $(element_selector).length !== 0) {

var divname515e62e8355b0 = '#test_selector';
$(divname515e62e8355b0).children().wrapAll('<div class="mydoc cf">');

//jQuery UI Position code here

}

 });
</script>
```

But I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

This is the problem line:

```
$(divname515e62e8355b0).children().wrapAll('<div class="mydoc cf">');
```

I've checked for commas, semicolons and there seems fine.
What could be the problem?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because in your second code, `$` is an event object, `.load()` doesn't behave like `.ready()` method,  If you want to avoid conflict use a self-invoking function:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(event) {
        // ...
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This helped me realize that using $( document ).raedy() and jQuery( document ).ready() are different things.