# Jquery click event don't want to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have read a lot of questions here about click function and i try to follow the answers, but i can't make it work.
There is definitely logical problem. 
Does not matter what is lower the 2nd line, because the console.log doesn't logs anything.
Here is the code:

```
$('#play')[0].click(function() {
    console.log('click'); 
    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop : arrOfDivs[2].offset().top - 80
    }, 700);
return false;
});
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3y88/

Thanks!

Comment: Why `[0]`? Remove it.

Comment: And read the doc : http://api.jquery.com/click/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i updated your code  http://jsfiddle.net/W3y88/3/

```
$('#play').on("click",function() {
    alert('click');
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue here is that when you declare an ID, you can only use it once on the page. If you want to affect multiple instances, you should consider using classes on those items you want to alter.

Try changing your id to a class, then change your code to:

```
$('.play').click(function() {
console.log('click'); 
$("html,body").animate({
    scrollTop : arrOfDivs[2].offset().top - 80
}, 700);
return false;});
```

Of course, I am assuming you have given multiple objects the same **id**. If you could paste more code, it would be helpful.

A reference on ID's: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

Alternately, you can remove the [0] if you are referring to a unique **ID** and your original code may work.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/DWU5Y/

But, you had few thigns missing:

- The `script` include for Jquery.
- The `id` is unique so I am not sure why you used `$('#id')[0]`
- doc.ready vs windows load: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/document-ready-and-window-onload-difference

Further if you keen : [Running jQuery inside $(window).load() function but not inside $(document).ready function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826498/running-jquery-inside-window-load-function-but-not-inside-document-ready)

- http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

`:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#play').click(function () {
        alert('click');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it will work.

$('#clickme').live ('click', function (){
 Things to do
})